# pairwise.t.test in R returns null values

Tags: r

I am running a pairwise t tests in R with a bonferroni adj. I have no problem running the tests with all the different categories of my data except one. Results for the t.tests between a certain measurement and plant categories like eater or group are normal. When I run the tests to compare that measurement by specified type of plant I get this result:

```
Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  `plants$dC and plants$type` 
   dg gr hb li sh
gr -  -  -  -  - 
hb -  -  -  -  - 
li -  -  -  -  - 
sh -  -  -  -  - 
tr -  -  -  -  -
```

My code is:

```
ttestCtype <-pairwise.t.test(plants$dC, plants$type, p.adj="bonferroni") #ttest of dC by type
ttestCtype #displays results
```

This is identical to code used for t-tests for plants by group that come out fine.

My data looks like

```
Specimen    dC  dN  prC prN name    part    eater   group   type
GMBP008 -14.12  4.19    43.09   3.93    bwomfu  grass leaves    ba  gr  gr
GMBP112 -12.23  -0.72   45.5    1.29    bwomfu  grass leaves    ba  gr  gr
GMBP102 -12.9   1.1 54.77   0.91    bwomfu  uso ba  gr  gr
GMBP106 -12.79  3.31    54.8    0.65    bwomfu  uso ba  gr  gr
GMBP081 -12.45  -2.34   43.19   1.39    nyababa pith    bo  gr  gr
```

I have double checked my data for NAs, nulls, etc.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: can you print the output of str(plants) please? Maybe you could also format the data, I think it was reformatted because new lines are deleted ;) (Just use 4 spaces before each rows and it is formatted like code)

Comment: It's possible that the `type` column actually contains multiple datapoints in each row, which would throw an error. There are also other possible reasons that `type` could experience an error when being converted to a factor by the T-test. Verena is exactly right in requesting `str(plant)`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises when there exists a group with only one item in it. For example:

```
pairwise.t.test(1:7, c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"))
```

returns:

```
    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  1:7 and c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D") 

  A B C
B - - -
C - - -
D - - -

P value adjustment method: holm
```

The solution is to filter out any groups that occur only once before doing the t-test (such tests wouldn't be meaningful anyway). For instance, this could be done in base R or dplyr:

```
# Base R
plants_filtered <- plants[tapply(plants$type, plants$type, length), ]

# dplyr
plants_filtered <- plants %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2) %>%
  ungroup()
```